# Google Sheets Filter Function based on condition

Tags: google-sheets

I am trying to create a filter function based on a condition, but when the condition is false I receive the error saying that the array returns empty rows.. Anything I can do?

```
={IF($C5,SORT(FILTER($AE3:$BL,$AF$3:$AF=$D5),1,TRUE),"");
IF($C6,SORT(FILTER($AE3:$BL,$AF$3:$AF=$D6),1,TRUE),"");
IF($C7,SORT(FILTER($AE3:$BL,$AF$3:$AF=$D7),1,TRUE),"");
IF($C8,SORT(FILTER($AE3:$BL,$AF$3:$AF=$D8),1,TRUE),"");
IF($C9,SORT(FILTER($AE3:$BL,$AF$3:$AF=$D),1,TRUE),"");
IF($C10,SORT(FILTER($AE3:$BL,$AF$3:$AF=$D10),1,TRUE),"")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You might try this formula:

```
=QUERY(AE3:BL,"where AF matches '"&JOIN("|",FILTER(D5:D10,C5:C10))&"' order by AF,AE",0)
```

or this if you prefer, but just didn't know how to ask:

```
=QUERY(AE3:BL,"where AF matches '"&JOIN("|",FILTER(D5:D10,C5:C10))&"' order by AE",0)
```